# How can i receive errors having status code 500 only on self hosted sentry

Tags: python, pyramid, sentry

I have hosted sentry, now sentry report two types of errors :

1) exceptions that are not handled by any exception view(4XX)

2) exceptions whose exception view returns a status code of 500

I only want to receive those exceptions whose exception view returns a status code of 500.

I am unable to find any option to do it.

Just for reference, i am using sentry to track issue in Pyramid(python) project.

Comment: Because sentry is written in Django and from what i have seen, anyone who have read the codebase can answer this question.

Comment: which version of the SDK are you running? This has more to do with the SDK and less with Django or Sentry server.

Comment: First make sure you [satisfied requirements](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/). Then according to the [Pyramid integration](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/pyramid/): "The SDK will report all exceptions leading to an Internal Server Error. These two kinds of exceptions are: * exceptions that are not handled by any exception view, * exceptions whose exception view returns a status code of 500 (Pyramid version 1.9+ only)".

Comment: Yep, I wanted to return only those exceptions whose exception view returns a status code of 500. 
Edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: Looking for similar kind of things. Please guide if anybody has tried to implement same.